# Retrieve package name of applications whom are currently running in Android

Tags: android, package

Can someone help me with sample code on retrieving the packages names of the activities that are currently running in Android?

Edited:

Code 1

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (processes != null){
        for (int i=0; i<processes.size(); i++){
            RunningAppProcessInfo temp = processes.get(i);
            String pName = temp.processName;
            for (int k=0; k<blacklist.size(); k++){
                if (pName.equalsIgnoreCase((String)blacklist.get(k))){
                    int pid = android.os.Process.getUidForName(pName);
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
                }
            }
     }
```

Code 2?

```
  int pid = temp.pid;
    String[] packages = temp.pkgList;
            for (int j=0; j<packages.length; j++){
                String packageName = packages[j];
                for (int k=0; k<blacklist.size(); k++){
                    if (packageName.equalsIgnoreCase((String)blacklist.get(k))){
                        //Android 2.2+ kill all background processes
                        am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Assuming that black has the application package name of program which I have blacklisted and want to terminate. Which of the above code is the correct way in which to implement my task killer. Can someone explain the difference between killBackgroundProcesses(packageName) and android.os.Process.killProcess(pid) as I cant seem to get the difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **getRunningAppProcesses** on the Android **ActivityManager** to retrieve a list of running processes.

Check this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29

You can use the **getInstalledPackages** method on the Android **PackageManager** to retrieve a list of all the installed apps

Check this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29

Comment: Erm. I'm not trying to find the applications that are installed, but are currently running in the fore or background.

Comment: I did try using getRunningAppProcesses. But I'm not sure about how it works. Is it that i can get a list of running processes and from each process info get the package of its application by using the am.getRunningAppProcesses().get(i).pkgList which returns a String

Comment: pkgList returns all packages that have been loaded into that process.

Comment: Sorry if I sound like a noob, but by package does it means the imported packages?
Basically I'm trying to create a task killer which matches the blacklisted apps list that I've created to the current running applications. Then killing them.

Comment: You should try it. The method described in my answer should answer your original question.

Comment: I've edited the main question to the code above. Much appreciated if you can help me take a look. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's not the way this site works. You can't keep adding stuff to an already asked and answered question :) Otherwize I can keep on answering different things.

Comment: Just really new to android and time isnt at my side. Can be really frustrating to code and yet not getting the results I want. But thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        ActivityManager am =(ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
  ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task = tasks.get(0); // current task
   ComponentName rootActivity = task.baseActivity;


      rootActivity.getPackageName();//*currently active applications package name*
```

using this in a loop,you will get package name of all currently running app ,to get running app name, see this [EXAMPLE](http://shortcutsandroid.blogspot.in/2015/02/how-to-get-package-name-in-android.html)

Comment: getRunningTasks is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

first of you API greater then 20 then use the bellow code to definitely work. I use this code and work properly. Try it

```
String currentApp=null;
    UsageStatsManager usm= (UsageStatsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
    long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<UsageStats> applist=usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY,time - 1000*1000,time);
    if(applist !=null && applist.size() > 0)
    {
        SortedMap<Long,UsageStats> mySortedMap=new TreeMap<Long,UsageStats>();
        for (UsageStats usageStats : applist)
        {
            mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),usageStats);

        }
        if(mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty())
        {
            currentApp=mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
        }
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Current App in foreground is: " + currentApp);

    return currentApp;
```